# How to completely clear all User Environment variables in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables

I've been trying to make any progress I can in porting a company product written and heavily leaning on Unix, into a Windows compatible build. It's not going so well. I have two different development branches with two different problems. In this problem, I have to port what is essentially a wrapper for the Unix `clearenv()` function, which completely clears all user environment variables from the table. Probably for security reasons, I could not find an equivalent to `clearenv()` for Windows, and the one solution I found/came up with, would wipe away all environment variables in the process, including system variables. I want a solution that would get rid of all user environment variables, but not touch system ones.

I know it may be a dumb thing to do, but it's in the code, so I have to try to port it.

Also, if it helps, I'm compiling under MinGW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [CreateEnvironmentBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270(v=vs.85).aspx):

> hToken [in, optional]
>   [...] If this parameter is NULL, the returned environment block contains system variables only.

It will still be a bit messy to go through the process environment block and change it to match the "system only" block that this function returns, but at least you'll have the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a simple function to delete the current environment variable.

firstly, you can use the function CreateEnvironmentBlock to retrieve block that contains whole key array.

secondly, use function SetEnvironmentVariable to loop all the key with value of NULL, this will delete the environment value.